# UNIX find dirs that contain a particular file (pom.xml) then execute command in that dir

Tags: unix, find, script

I want to, from  a root dir, find all dirs that contain a certain file name (pom.xml), then cd to that dir and execute a command. I can do this in a script but I was hoping to do this with a single line command.

so far I have

```
find . -type f -name 'pom.xml' |sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#'
```

This gives the dirs I need... now I need to cd into each and execute my command

Comment: why do you need to cd to the directory to execute your command?  Just execute the command on `/path/to/pom.xml`

Comment: This question clearly says you aren't writing any kind of shell script, it belongs on superuser

Comment: @tim he's trying to avoid programming which should be any programmers first thought ;)

Comment: @ dnagirl the command is executing a script that creates new dirs etc in the dir with the pom.xml file

@ want is as a one liner so its easy to distribute

Answer (score 6):

find has -exec and -execdir. For a maven build, you'd do

```
# executes `mvn clean install` in any directory where pom.xml was found
find . -name pom.xml -execdir mvn clean install \;
```

Comment: `-execdir` is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This will find the directories:

```
find . -name pom.xml -printf '%h\n'
```

then you could read the directories and run your command:

```
find . -name pom.xml -printf '%h\n' | while read dir; do ( cd "$dir"; command ... ) done
```

If you're paranoid about embedded newlines in directory names (and seriously, what's wrong with people?) you can use "\0" in the printf, and then use `xargs` to run the command:

```
find . -name pom.xml -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c 'dir="$0"; cd "$dir"; command ...'
```

Answer (score 1):

there's also:

```
find . -type f -exec mvn -f {} clean install \;
```

However, I think you should be looking at the available Maven options to do this. While it's no longer present in Maven 3.x, Maven 2.x has the `-r` option which does exactly this. A better way is to create an aggregating `pom.xml` that contains the desired files as modules, and you can then use the `-rf` and `-pl` to selectively choose which to build.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to apply the svnignore properties based on a file from which you don't know the absolute path you could use:

```
#!/bin/sh
find -name pom.xml -execdir pwd \; | while read project_dir
do
svn propset svn:ignore -F support-tools/svn/svnignore.cfg $project_dir
done
```

I use this one in my current projects, as each developer has the svn checkout on a different location and it doesn't change the working dir from which to execute the svn command. For other purposes use

```
find -name -execdir
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xargs`:

> ```
>  xargs -- construct argument list(s) and execute utility
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
>         [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
>         [utility [argument ...]]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  The xargs utility reads space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited
>  strings from the standard input and executes utility with the strings
>  as arguments.
>
>  Any arguments specified on the command line are given to utility upon
>  each invocation, followed by some number of the arguments read from the
>  standard input of xargs.  The utility is repeatedly executed until stan-
>  dard input is exhausted.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find / -type f -name 'pom.xml' -print | while read FILE; do cd `dirname ${FILE}` && /run/my/script; done
```

If you can change the script so that it takes a directory as an argument then the following should work:

```
find / -type f -name 'pom.xml' -exec /run/my/script `dirname {}` \;
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the unique folders containing a given file type you can use:

`find . -type f -name *.png | sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' | uniq`

This will list all the unique directories including PNG files.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer –– to a _different_ question.  This has only the slimmest relationship to the question that was actually asked here.